# Cannot pass value variable to WP AJAX functions

Tags: plugins, functions, ajax, jquery

I create plugin to create wizards using jquery steps.
I save all step's values into variable and using ajax to process it, then show using wp ajax function

but only one variable in ajax inserted into wp ajax function, other one value empty but when I see inside console log after ajax success. it have have value.

only variable `answer` have value but `results_wizard` don't have value.

```
    var answer = [], results_wizards = [],
    stepsWizard = jQuery("#wizard").steps({
        headerTag: "h2",
        bodyTag: "section",
        transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
        enablePagination: false,
        titleTemplate: "#title#",

        onStepChanged: function (event, currentIndex, priorIndex) { 
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#row-wizard-letselschade").offset().top - 80
            });
            $('input[name="wiz-'+priorIndex+'"]:checked').each(function(i){
                if(jQuery.inArray($(this).val(),answer) == -1){
                    // the element is not in the array
                    answer.push($(this).val());
                    results_wizards[$(this).val()] = $("label[for='"+this.id+"']").text();
                    
                };
                
            
                
            });
            $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function(i){
                var removeItem = $(this).val();
                answer = jQuery.grep(answer, function(value) {
                      return value != removeItem;
                    });
                });
            
            },
        onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)
        {
            $('input[name="wiz-'+currentIndex+'"]:checked').each(function(i){
                if(jQuery.inArray($(this).val(),answer) == -1){
                    // the element is not in the array
                    answer.push( $(this).val());
                }; 
                
            });
            
            var dataAnswerNew = {
                    'action': 'wizard_answers',
                    'answer':answer, 
                    'results_wizards': results_wizards,
                };
            $.post(whwz_ajaxurl, dataAnswerNew, function(response){
                console.log(results_wizards);
                $('.wizard-answer').html(response);
                
                var form_id = $('.wpcf7').attr('id');
                $('.wpcf7 > form').attr('action', '/#' + form_id);
                wpcf7.initForm( jQuery('.wpcf7-form') );
                
                

                });
        }
    });
```

here my ajax

```
  var dataAnswerNew = {
                'action': 'wizard_answers',
                'answer':answer, 
                'results_wizards': results_wizards,
            };
        $.post(whwz_ajaxurl, dataAnswerNew, function(response){
            console.log(results_wizards);
            $('.wizard-answer').html(response);

            var form_id = $('.wpcf7').attr('id');
            $('.wpcf7 > form').attr('action', '/#' + form_id);
            wpcf7.initForm( jQuery('.wpcf7-form') );



            });
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? I'm not sure I understand. Also remember that pure javascript questions should go on stackoverflow

Comment: @TomJNowell thank you.  basically, I use the way wordpress to make responses. AJAX response send to wp_ajax function. but wp_ajax only fetch one variable instead of two variables.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean, you never explained what the variables are or where they come from. There's also no code for the PHP side that handles AJAX